# HTML Button Display but you can't interact with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have an HTML button on my webpage. It will display but you can't interact with it. Both hovering and clicking on the button seems to do nothing. When you click the button a menu is supposed to appear and when you hover the button is supposed to turn red. The problem is the button can't be interacted with.

```js
var mobileMenuButton = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-enter");
var mobileMenu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-id");

var mobileMenuButtonOnClick = function() {
  mobileMenu.classList.remove("hidden");
};

mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("click", mobileMenuButtonOnClick);
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 0;
}

.mr-0 {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.nav-bar {
  z-index: 98;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.8);
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav-img {
  height: 100px;
}

.nav-options {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.nav-option {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: large;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 0.5px;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-nav-options {
  display: table;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}

.hamburger-menu :hover {
  color: red;
}

.desktop-nav {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/20852/images/magazine_medium/axolotl_WWsummer2021.jpg?1618758847" class="nav-img"></a>
    <div class="nav-options">
      <button class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto hamburger-menu" id="mobile-menu-enter">
                      <div class="line"></div><br>
                       <div class="line"></div><br>
                      <div class="line"></div>
                      The button that is not working
                    </button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="hidden" id="mobile-menu-id">
    the menu
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have div elements in your button. See [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#try_it).

Comment: @Andy it worked before. Also tried changing the button element to a div. No success

Comment: Like many things just because you can do something doesn't mean you should :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete space between `.hamburger-menu` and `:hover`. Event `click` on `mobileMenuButton` works.

```js
var mobileMenuButton = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-enter");
var mobileMenu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-id");

var mobileMenuButtonOnClick = function() {
  mobileMenu.classList.remove("hidden");
};

mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("click", mobileMenuButtonOnClick);
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 0;
}

.mr-0 {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.nav-bar {
  z-index: 98;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.8);
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav-img {
  height: 100px;
}

.nav-options {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.nav-option {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: large;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 0.5px;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-nav-options {
  display: table;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}

.hamburger-menu:hover {
  color: red;
}

.desktop-nav {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/20852/images/magazine_medium/axolotl_WWsummer2021.jpg?1618758847" class="nav-img"></a>
    <div class="nav-options">
      <button class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto hamburger-menu" id="mobile-menu-enter">
                      <div class="line"></div><br>
                       <div class="line"></div><br>
                      <div class="line"></div>
                      The button that is not working
                    </button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="hidden" id="mobile-menu-id">
    the menu
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The hover still doesn't work. However, that was mainly for testing purposes. Otherwise, this works great!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the **.toggle()** method instead from the classList object to best interact with the hiding and showing on the menu of the left. Additionally, to simulate the burger menu, use a SVG code instead so it looks more pro, as well as adding the red background you are looking for, something like the one on the code below. Take a look at this snippet of code. I certainly hope this helps, pal!

```js
var mobileMenuButton = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-enter");
var mobileMenu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-id");

var mobileMenuButtonOnClick = function() {
  mobileMenu.classList.toggle("hidden");
};

mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("click", mobileMenuButtonOnClick);
```

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size: large;
    margin: 0;
}

.mr-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.ml-auto {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.d-block {
    display: block;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.nav-bar {
    z-index: 98;
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.8);
    padding: 15px;
}

.nav-img {
    height: 100px;
}

.nav-options {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.nav-option {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: large;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.line {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 0.5px;
}

.mobile-nav {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}

.mobile-nav-options {
    display: table;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}

.hamburger-menu:hover {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.desktop-nav {
    display: none;
}

.mobile-nav {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
   <nav class="mobile-nav">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/20852/images/magazine_medium/axolotl_WWsummer2021.jpg?1618758847" class="nav-img"></a>
      <div class="nav-options">
         <button class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto hamburger-menu" id="mobile-menu-enter">
            <!--?xml version="1.0" ?-->
            <svg style="color: white" height="32px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
               <path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2 s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2 S29.104,22,28,22z" fill="white"></path>
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </nav>
   <div class="hidden w-50" id="mobile-menu-id">
      MENU GOES HERE
   </div>
</div>
```